# FlinkKafkaConsumer - Scala consume json message

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to scala and flink. I am using the following code to consume a json message from a kafka stream.

```
object Job {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    // only required for Kafka 0.8
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
    val topic: String = "test"

    val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[ObjectNode](topic, new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), properties)
    // set up the execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val stream = env.addSource(consumer).name("opendental")
      .enableCheckpointing(5000) // checkpoint every 5000 msecs
      .print()

    // execute program
    env.execute("Flink Scala API Skeleton")
  }
}
```

I am using the command `mvn clean package` to compile the scala code to a `.jar` but the build fails due to an overloaded method. This is the error

```
[ERROR]   (x$1: java.util.regex.Pattern,x$2: org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedDeserializationSchema[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode],x$3: java.util.Properties)org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode] <and>
[ERROR]   (x$1: java.util.regex.Pattern,x$2: (some other)org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema(in <none>)[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode],x$3: java.util.Properties)org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode] <and>
[ERROR]   (x$1: java.util.List[String],x$2: org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedDeserializationSchema[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode],x$3: java.util.Properties)org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode] <and>
[ERROR]   (x$1: java.util.List[String],x$2: org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema(in <none>)[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode],x$3: java.util.Properties)org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode] <and>
[ERROR]   (x$1: String,x$2: org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedDeserializationSchema[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode],x$3: java.util.Properties)org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode] <and>
[ERROR]   (x$1: String,x$2: org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode],x$3: java.util.Properties)org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode]
[ERROR]  cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema, java.util.Properties)
[ERROR]     val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[ObjectNode](topic, new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), properties)
[ERROR]
```

I have tried several things to resolve the overloaded method, but now I have hit a wall.

Comment: You might want to try using an IDE along with maven. Then you can see your compilation errors

Comment: I only displayed a small portion of the error code displayed

Comment: I understand that, but I mean you should be seeing the errors before trying to run `mvn clean package`. Have you got your code to work with `SimpleStringSchema`? Also, note the comment above zoookeper "only required for Kafka 0.8", which I would like to think you're not running if only starting using kafka